# Find hexadecimal entites and code span element in xslt transformation

Tags: xml, entity, xslt-1.0

I need to transform hexadecimal entites from xml to another xml in xslt as like below example. Kindly advice.

Input:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<book>
<p>King&#x00027;s College</p>
<p>This is greek &#x00391;</p>
<p>This is arrow &#x021D5;</p>
</book>
```

Expected Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<book>
<p>King<font name="Times">&#x00027;</font>s College</p>
<p>This is greek <font name="Symbol">&#x00391;</font></p>
<p>This is arrow <font name="Symbol">&#x021D5;</font></p>
</book>
```

Answer (score 0):

XSLT operates at a level of abstraction in which numeric character references have been resolved; there is no difference, in the relevant data model, between `<p>King&#x27;s College</p>` and `<p>King's College</p>`, or between `<p>&x21D5;</p>` and `<p>⇕</p>`.

I think you have three plausible options:

- search for the characters in question using `contains` or (in 2.0) the regular-expression function of your choice, and do the right thing -- this won't work if you want to handle a literal apostrophe and `&#x27;` differently.
- use sed or Perl -- it's easy enough to write a regular expression to match hexadecimal numeric character references, and they are guaranteed not to span multiple lines.  Your only problem will be that in sed or Perl it's not so easy to avoid inserting `font` tags in the middle of an attribute value, should the numeric character reference show up there.
- upgrade your downstream display technology to support Unicode properly and avoid the need for font shifts of this kind.

If it were me, I'd really prefer the third of these; failing that, either of the other two should work, unless the XML you are processing has made some really really unlucky design decisions.